# Let $A \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a singular matrix. Let $x_0$ and $b$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax_0=b$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a singular matrix. Let $x_0$ and $b$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax_0=b$. Which of the following statements are true?

(a) There exists $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A^{T}y_0=b$.

(b) There exists infinitely many solutions to the equation $Ax=b$.

(c) If $A^T x=0$, then it follows that $b^T x=0$.

> Solution:

For (b) part,  since the matrix is singular, the rank of the matrix is less than min(number of rows, number of columns). It follows from here that Nullity of matrix is atleast one. Also from the result that the number of solutions for $Ax=b$ is given by $(|\mathbb{F}| )^k$, where $|\mathbb{F}|$ is he number of elements in the field and $k$ is the nullity of the matrix. Here, $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb R$ and $k\ge1$, hence there exists infinitely many solutions to the equation $Ax=b$.

How do I proceed for options (a) and (c). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (c), the condition on $x$ is the same as asking that $x$ is in the space orthogonal the the column-span of $A$ (where orthogonality is for the standard inner product). Asking $b=Ax_0$ tells you that $b$ is the column space, so you can conclude.

For (a), it is not always true. For example, take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so that $A^t = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. For $b= [1, 0]$, we have $Ax = b$ for any $x= [ \lambda, 1]$, while $A^ty_0$ will always have its first coordinate equal to $0$.

Comment: I did not understand the part (c) what you explained, please try to explain more.

Comment: Let's call $V$ the column-span, or image, or range of $A$. It has an orthogonal space $V^\perp = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n\,:\, y^tx = 0\, \forall~x \in V\}$. It is a fact that $V^\perp = \ker A^t$: if $x \in V$, then it can be written $x = Ax'$ for some $x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and if $y\in V^\perp$, then $y^t(Ax') = (A^ty)^tx' = 0$. Now, in (c) it is assumed that you are given $x$ such that $A^tx = 0$, or equivalently, $x \in \ker A^t$, while $b =Ax_0$, or equivalently, $b\in V$. Is it better?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the help.